# Glossary page list spacing

Tags: spacing, glossaries-extra

I am compiling a document with a glossary using `\RequirePackage[xindy]{glossaries-extra}` as well as a personalised glossary style.

```
%% Glossary
\newglossarystyle{myGlossStyle}{
    \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{
    \bf{Abbreviation} & \bf{Description} & \bf{Page} 
    \vspace{5pt}
    \endhead}}
\setglossarystyle{myGlossStyle}
\preto\chapter{\glsresetall}
\makeglossary
```

Some of my entries are for example:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newacronym{ilp}{ILP}{Integer Linear Programming}
\newacronym[longplural={Linear Matrix Inequalities}]{lmi}{LMI}{Linear Matrix Inequality}
\newacronym{lp}{LP}{Linear Programming}
```

Although, pdfTeX is complaining that the spacing in the page list column has under-full boxes, and when I look at it, the spacing is indeed not consistent.

[image]

I had a look around but I didn't see any way to fix this issue so far.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fix that might hopefully be useful to other people,

```
%% Glossary
\newglossarystyle{myGlossStyle}{
    \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{
    \bf{Abbreviation} & \bf{Description} & \bf{Page}
    \vspace{7.5pt}
    \endhead}}
\setglossarystyle{myGlossStyle}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.6\linewidth} % change description width
\setlength{\glspagelistwidth}{0.2\linewidth} % change page list width
\preto\chapter{\glsresetall}
\makeglossary
```

Changing the width of the description and page list, modifies the spacing between the page numbers and solve the problem.

Hope it will be helpful to others as well.

Romain